# How do you defeat yourself or: How do I defeat myself?

Tags: candy-box

I recently got [a quest to fight "myself"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116173/4797), an opponent with the exact same HP and sword as I:

[image]

---

**What are effective ways to defeat one's self?**

Also, I realized that [if you have too much HP (by eating too much candy), this will make the quest take *too long* to finish](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116155/4797). Aside from not eating too much candy, **are there other ways to make this quest easier and faster to finish, like which choice of sword and other items to use?**

**Do the effects of the swords activate when fighting yourself?** i.e. Will fighting yourself with the [Life Sword](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116108/4797) make the quest longer to finish as both you and yourself (your clone) are continually healing themselves on every hit? What about the effects of the [Fire Sword and the Sword of Summoning](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116108/4797)?

---

From a question closed as a duplicate of this one ([What does the sorceress mean by being "able to surpass yourself"?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116151/4797)):

The sorceress recently gave me an option to buy the ability to "*surpass myself*" in exchange for a million lollipops. I bought that ability. Afterwards, the sorceress now says this:

[image: Sorceress: You are now able to surpass yourself. Congratulations !]
<sup>You are now able to surpass yourself. Congratulations !</sup>

- What triggers the sorceress into selling you the ability to surpass
  yourself?
- **And what does it mean if I am now "able to surpass myself"?**
- **What changes do the "ability to surpass yourself" do?** (I'm asking this mainly to know [how cheats could have a side effect on this game mechanic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116155/4797).)

  - An [approved edit by an anonymous user in this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/116283/3) states that: "*The Surpass Yourself increases the damage done to the You (Clone) while not damaging You (Player), making the level completable.*" However, this conflicts with [this other answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116651/4797): "*The "Surpass Yourself" spell basically prevents the real you from dying when you battle yourself. When you get down to 0 health, the real you will be given 1 health, allowing you to complete the level.*". Can anyone confirm how exactly the game mechanics work here?

Comment: I had a lot of health too, but I just used the Chrome console to set the berserk potion timer to a silly number and left it alone while I did my job. I'm sure you could just change your hero health and I think the duplicate's stats all mirror to your current ones.

Comment: As for the game mechanics: The second answer is correct. The damage.js file states (from line 160 on) that your original character's hp are set to 1 when dropping to zero while your clone stays dead: `if(land.getLandIndexFromName("Yourself") == quest.currentLandIndex && yourself.canSurpass == true && theFirstIsTheCharacter == true){
            if(quest.things[i].hp == 0){
                quest.things[i].hp = 1;
                yourself.end = true;
            }
        }`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two solutions to this level. The first solution, as mentioned before, is to pay the sorceress the sum of 1 million lollipops. Now this doesn't sound all that appealing. This is the easy way to do it.

However, if you want to save yourself the lollipops and time, fight yourself and wait until the moment you drop under 25 life to cast a fire scroll. Easy win if you can time it right.

I had about 400 life when I killed myself, so health wasn't an issue. I suppose the fire enchanted sword would be optimal since it does additional damage.

Comment: +1 for fire scroll, so much easier than 1m lollipops, especially since you'll probably have dozens of them left over from trying to buy teleport scrolls.

Comment: To add to this answer, "*The "Surpass Yourself" spell basically prevents the real you from dying when you battle yourself. When you get down to 0 health, the real you will be given 1 health, allowing you to complete the level.*" - [from an answer here by @Alex](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116651/4797)

Answer (score 3):

Pay the sorceress 1 million lollipops to 'surpass yourself', only then can you win.

Any scrolls or potions etc. affect both of yourself, resulting in no net advantage.

Comment: [What changes do the "surpass yourself" ability do?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116151/4797)

Comment: Or use a fire scroll when below 25 HP. Just did it, way easier than waiting for 1MLP

Answer (score 1):

The "Surpass Yourself" spell basically prevents the real you from dying when you battle yourself. When you get down to 0 health, the real you will be given 1 health, allowing you to complete the level.