# How do I beat myself after taking the X Potion?

Tags: candy-box-2

When I use the X Potion from any level, I get teleported to an area where I fight myself. But, I can't seem to win!

Whenever I try to heal, the other me heals as well, so I keep dying before I can kill myself! How can I win?

Comment: [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116200/how-do-you-defeat-yourself-or-how-do-i-defeat-myself) is related, from the original Candy Box. (I'm not sure by how much though as I've yet to play #2.)

Answer (score 6):

You can find the answer by reading the scrolling text in the background (use the time slowing ring if you find it hard to read). The answer:

> Wear the crown you get from killing the Octopus King and just autoattack. You'll survive on 1HP.

Comment: This didn't work for me...

Comment: It seems to not work if you have enchanted the crown. hmmmm. Does anyone know how to disenchant it?

Comment: Oh, I see. you just get another one.

Answer (score 2):

You must obtain the Octopus King's crown by beating him in the cave. Afterwards, you'll have Self Confidence and can kill your doppelganger. Otherwise, you die when your doppelganger dies.