# What's the use in killing myself?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've figured out the x potion riddle, but despite killing myself on numerous occasions I cannot see a use in it, because I get no drops. Am I doing something wrong, or *is killing myself really not going to get me anywhere in life?*

Comment: Related: [How do I beat myself after taking the X potion?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137075)

Comment: @Blue Oh, I didn't see that. It didn't show up in the thing that shows titles close to yours because the titles really aren't. This should be marked duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are misunderstanding what it means to kill yourself vs defeat yourself.
If you aren't getting the drop, then you are dying at the same time. That's no good.

Wear the Crown. Then you can actually "defeat yourself".

Answer (score 3):

You get these pair of boots that allow you not to move. It is great for farming, but I haven't found any other use for them really. I beat the entire game without ever using them to beat a level or stage.

Comment: I don't think you understand, I meant why am I not getting any drops from killing the mimic? I heard that you should receive 10% of your current crown count, but do you need a special item or something?

Comment: Why are you even trying to farm money that way. You can just use the boots and afk farm the castle entrance. And as far as I can remember, you don't get anything from repeatedly killing yourself

Comment: They are also good for a few other situations (I had a lot of luck using them on the Devil fight)